# How to install VLC in Fedora 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 or 21?

Tags: installation, fedora, vlc-media-player

I want to install the VLC player in my Fedora 20.

In https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-fedora.html they mention how to do it just up to the version 14.

What steps do I have to follow for bigger versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK [I found it](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/08/how-to-install-vlc-in-fedora-15/):

> yum localinstall --nogpgcheck
>   http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm
>   -E %fedora).noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm
>   -E %fedora).noarch.rpm

Note this uses `rpm -E %fedora` to get the version number. So if you already know it, you can say:

> yum localinstall --nogpgcheck
>   http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-20.noarch.rpm
>   http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-20.noarch.rpm

That is:

```
yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-20.noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-20.noarch.rpm
                                                                                                 ^^                                                                                   ^^
```